# Can't return the result from a subroutine in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Here's the batch file I'm trying to use:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal
FOR %%R IN ("SRC" "COMMON" "SCRIPTS") DO (
  call :CheckRepo %%R
  IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (@echo Repository %%R revision is top) else (@echo Repository %%R is revision wrong)
)

goto END

:CheckRepo
pushd .
cd %1
FOR /F "delims=^+^ " %%A IN ('hg id') DO (set revision=%%A)

FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%A IN ('hg branches') DO (
  IF "%%A" EQU "default" (
    IF "%%B" EQU "%revision%" (goto EXIT_OK) else (goto EXIT_ERROR)
  )
)

:EXIT_OK
popd
@echo This repository is on top revision
Exit /B 0

:EXIT_ERROR
popd
@echo This repository is NOT on top revision. Top is %revision%
Exit /B 1

:END
```

ERRORLEVEL is always zero, even though I have "This repository is NOT on top revision" in output for some directories. But on top level it either prints "Repository <name> is revision wrong" for **all** directories, or "Repository <name> revision is top" again for **all** directories. Like it writes some value once into ERRORLEVEL then just uses it and ignores my values returned via Exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with [conditional](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) execution:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal
FOR %%R IN ("SRC" "COMMON" "SCRIPTS") DO (
  call :CheckRepo %%R && (
    @echo Repository %%R revision is top ) || (
    @echo Repository %%R is revision wrong
  )
)
```

Comment: Yes conditional execution works, but why didn't it work with ERRORLEVEL?

Comment: because `if errorlevel 0` tells you, if errorlevel is _zero or higher_.

Comment: @user2846246 - see the Stephan's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this errorlevel check to test for specific values.

`if "%errorlevel%" == "0"`

or if needed...

`if "!errorlevel!" == "0"`

Comment: in this case this will not work without delayed expansion

Comment: Yes agreed.  I was just pointing out that %errorlevel% can be tested specifically instead of the Equal or Greater Than test that errorlevel provides.